# beautiful-soup vs beautifulsoup

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

For some reason, CR has a tag for the [`BeautifulSoup` library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) named as [`beautiful-soup`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beautiful-soup), with a hyphen even though there is no `-` in the official name of the package. SO has this tag named as [`beautifulsoup`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup).

Is it possible to rename it to be in sync with SO and the actual package name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess I never noticed it back when I was adding the wiki. Done!